# Do I need to create an Orchard 'Custom Theme' to Style a site with bespoke HTML/CSS?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I have HTML/CSS complete - conventional stuff.

I now need a CMS for this site. To use Orchard for this do I need to create a Custom Theme? (eg as in this article
http://www.deepcode.co.uk/2011/05/real-world-orchard-cms-part-2-creating.html

Or are custom themes for people that want to make something re-usable?

If there is an easier way to put Orchard CMS in a totally custom design - what is it?

Thx

Comment: What does "I have HTML/CSS complete" mean? What exactly do you mean by "totally custom design"? How would you expect this would work without a theme?

Comment: HTML/CSS is complete = I have the static HTML/CSS files completed.

Totally custom design = it is not based on any Orchard template.

Doing it without a theme - I am new to Orchard CMS. I'm checking that a Custom Theme is the best approach here (prudent before I do a lot of work I think - to ensure I'm not missing something).

Answer (score 1):

You definitely need to create your own theme. You could start with an existing theme and modify it, but if you've already got a static HTML/CSS design then you're probably best off starting from scratch.

For more information on theming you can check out:

- [Writing a new theme](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Writing-a-new-theme) - Orchard Documentation
- [Theming Orchard](http://www.nogginbox.co.uk/blog/theming-orchard) - A blog post I wrote a while ago

Studying the code of some existing themes can be a nice way to see how a theme is made up.

You should not directly modify the base template files inside Orchard modules. These are made to be overridden in your theme and modifying them directly will make updating Orchard very tricky.